# Updating firebase key name in developer console

Tags: android, firebase, google-play, google-play-services, google-developers-console

I'm setting up Firebase for my app for the first time. I followed the instructions and noticed that three API keys as well as one OAuth 2.0 Client ID were created in the developer console.

The API Keys:

1. Android key (auto created by Google Service)
2. Browser key (auto created by Google Service)
3. Server key (auto created by Google Service)

OAuth 2.0 Client ID

1. Web client (auto created by Google Service)

I want to rename these so that I know what they were. So I went into Firebase and figured out where they were being used and renamed them to the follwing:

1. Android key - Firebase - Web API Key
2. Browser key - Firebase (Not sure what this is used for)
3. Server key - Firebase - Cloud Message Legacy Servery Key
4. Web client - Firebase Application

However, when I rename them and redeploy my app, Firebase recreates new keys.

Now I have the following Api Keys:

1. Android key (auto created by Google Service)
2. Browser key (auto created by Google Service)
3. Server key (auto created by Google Service)
4. Android key - Firebase - Web API Key
5. Browser key - Firebase (Not sure what this is used for)
6. Server key - Firebase - Cloud Message Legacy Servery Key

The keys were remade.

The OAuth 2.0 Client ID was also changed back to the original name (Web client (auto created by Google Service))

I want to restrict these API keys and rename them. Is that possible?